# Download binary from GCS using HttpsOTAUpdate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, arduino, openssl, google-cloud-storage, esp32

So I'm trying to download a binary file from a GCS (google cloud storage) bucket to update the firmware of an `esp32` using the following supported structure:

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/examples/HTTPS_OTA_Update/HTTPS_OTA_Update.ino

code looks like this

```
// This sketch provide the functionality of OTA Firmware Upgrade
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "HttpsOTAUpdate.h"
// This sketch shows how to implement HTTPS firmware update Over The Air.
// Please provide your WiFi credentials, https URL to the firmware image and the server certificate.

static const char *ssid = "ssid";         // your network SSID (name of wifi network)
static const char *password = "psswd"; // your network password

static const char *url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/firmware.bin"; // state url of your firmware image

static const char *server_certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                                        "MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/\n"
                                        "MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT\n"
                                        "DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTE2MDMxNzE2NDA0NloXDTIxMDMxNzE2NDA0Nlow\n"
                                        "SjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQxIzAhBgNVBAMT\n"
                                        "GkxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQgQXV0aG9yaXR5IFgzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC\n"
                                        "AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnNMM8FrlLke3cl03g7NoYzDq1zUmGSXhvb418XCSL7e4S0EF\n"
                                        "q6meNQhY7LEqxGiHC6PjdeTm86dicbp5gWAf15Gan/PQeGdxyGkOlZHP/uaZ6WA8\n"
                                        "SMx+yk13EiSdRxta67nsHjcAHJyse6cF6s5K671B5TaYucv9bTyWaN8jKkKQDIZ0\n"
                                        "Z8h/pZq4UmEUEz9l6YKHy9v6Dlb2honzhT+Xhq+w3Brvaw2VFn3EK6BlspkENnWA\n"
                                        "a6xK8xuQSXgvopZPKiAlKQTGdMDQMc2PMTiVFrqoM7hD8bEfwzB/onkxEz0tNvjj\n"
                                        "/PIzark5McWvxI0NHWQWM6r6hCm21AvA2H3DkwIDAQABo4IBfTCCAXkwEgYDVR0T\n"
                                        "AQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwfwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEczBxMDIG\n"
                                        "CCsGAQUFBzABhiZodHRwOi8vaXNyZy50cnVzdGlkLm9jc3AuaWRlbnRydXN0LmNv\n"
                                        "bTA7BggrBgEFBQcwAoYvaHR0cDovL2FwcHMuaWRlbnRydXN0LmNvbS9yb290cy9k\n"
                                        "c3Ryb290Y2F4My5wN2MwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUxKexpHsscfrb4UuQdf/EFWCFiRAw\n"
                                        "VAYDVR0gBE0wSzAIBgZngQwBAgEwPwYLKwYBBAGC3xMBAQEwMDAuBggrBgEFBQcC\n"
                                        "ARYiaHR0cDovL2Nwcy5yb290LXgxLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZzA8BgNVHR8ENTAz\n"
                                        "MDGgL6AthitodHRwOi8vY3JsLmlkZW50cnVzdC5jb20vRFNUUk9PVENBWDNDUkwu\n"
                                        "Y3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSoSmpjBH3duubRObemRWXv86jsoTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n"
                                        "AAOCAQEA3TPXEfNjWDjdGBX7CVW+dla5cEilaUcne8IkCJLxWh9KEik3JHRRHGJo\n"
                                        "uM2VcGfl96S8TihRzZvoroed6ti6WqEBmtzw3Wodatg+VyOeph4EYpr/1wXKtx8/\n"
                                        "wApIvJSwtmVi4MFU5aMqrSDE6ea73Mj2tcMyo5jMd6jmeWUHK8so/joWUoHOUgwu\n"
                                        "X4Po1QYz+3dszkDqMp4fklxBwXRsW10KXzPMTZ+sOPAveyxindmjkW8lGy+QsRlG\n"
                                        "PfZ+G6Z6h7mjem0Y+iWlkYcV4PIWL1iwBi8saCbGS5jN2p8M+X+Q7UNKEkROb3N6\n"
                                        "KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==\n"
                                        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

static HttpsOTAStatus_t otastatus;

void HttpEvent(HttpEvent_t *event)
{
  switch (event->event_id)
  {
  case HTTP_EVENT_ERROR:
    Serial.println("Http Event Error");
    break;
  case HTTP_EVENT_ON_CONNECTED:
    Serial.println("Http Event On Connected");
    break;
  case HTTP_EVENT_HEADER_SENT:
    Serial.println("Http Event Header Sent");
    break;
  case HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER:
    Serial.printf("Http Event On Header, key=%s, value=%s\n", event->header_key, event->header_value);
    break;
  case HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA:
    break;
  case HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH:
    Serial.println("Http Event On Finish");
    break;
  case HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
    Serial.println("Http Event Disconnected");
    break;
  }
}

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  HttpsOTA.onHttpEvent(HttpEvent);
  Serial.println("Starting OTA");
  HttpsOTA.begin(url, server_certificate);

  Serial.println("Please Wait it takes some time ...");
}

void loop()
{
  otastatus = HttpsOTA.status();
  if (otastatus == HTTPS_OTA_SUCCESS)
  {
    Serial.println("Firmware written successfully. To reboot device, call API ESP.restart() or PUSH restart button on device");
  }
  else if (otastatus == HTTPS_OTA_FAIL)
  {
    Serial.println("Firmware Upgrade Fail");
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Starting OTA
Please Wait it takes some time ...
E (1547) esp-tls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700
E (1549) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (1549) TRANS_SSL: Failed to open a new connection
E (1550) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0
E (1554) esp_https_ota: Failed to open HTTP connection: ESP_ERR_HTTP_CONNECT
E (1561) esp_https_ota: Failed to establish HTTP connection
Http Event Disconnected
Http Event Disconnected
Firmware Upgrade Fail
Firmware Upgrade Fail
Firmware Upgrade Fail
```

I believe this is associated to the certificate used for TLS in the request.

Question is, how can I find/generate the right certificate to communicate with GCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe this is associated to the certificate used for TLS in the request.
> Yes, this may be the problem.

The `server_certificate` in your example is Let's Encrypt Authority certificate (C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3), but to establish the connection you might need server leaf certificate.

You can get it with OpenSSL. If you are connecting to https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/firmware.bin, then the command will look like this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername storage.googleapis.com -connect storage.googleapis.com:443 </dev/null
```

There will be several certificates in the output, you need to copy the first one and place it instead the Let's Encrypt one.

Comment: that was on spot. Thank you so much for this. Quick question, would this certificate rotate / refresh? Meaning I'd need to update it on the microcontrollers periodically?

Comment: Oh also, I'll make a comment on what needs to be copied. I copied all 3 certificates shown (chain certificate) for it to work! And it works perfectly. Does this maybe make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading stuff from a storage bucket requires authenticating your client. You can't just point an HTTPS client to a storage bucket URL and merrily download. You need to generate a OAuth2 token first, then include it in a header of your request:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object